# iPhone 4s issue

Tags: iphone, css

I've got a little issue with the gallery of [this page](http://creativusmouse.com/Proteus/html_preview/portfolio_4_col.html) 
.

On the iPhone 4S, when I click on an image and swipe through the gallery, a blank space on the right becomes visible. However this doesn't occur on other devices. I've been trying to fix this, but since I don't possess an iPhone 4S, things get a little harder and I have no clue what could be causing this issue.

Hope someone could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `initial-scale` in the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```